# Извлечь из json значение

Tags: python, json

Посредством requests.get я получаю такой json:

> {"results":{"c":[12,37],"i":"162455","p":142.1,"s":5,"x":4,"r":202,"z":3,"T":"AAPL","t":1633552753749759706,"y":1633552753747000000,"f":1633552753749735471,"q":6018382},"status":"OK","request_id":"35931240cb391dea6b8485d12d7c6625"}

не могу извлечь определенное значение ("p":142.1), а именно число 142.1

делал так:

```
async with session.get(url) as resp:
        resp_text = await resp.json()
        for result in resp_dict['results']:
             print(result['p'])
```

пишет:
**print(result['p'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import json
temp_dict = json.loads(resp.json())
print temp_dict['results']['p']
```

Comment: так тоже пробовал, выдает это: `temp_dict = json.loads(resp.json())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not coroutine`

Comment: Если строка, которую Вы привели, именно такая, то приведённый код работает, я только что проверил в python 3. Запишите Вашу строку из примера в какую-то переменную (например, *temp_str*) и выполните код для *temp_dict = json.loads(temp_str)*. Всё должно распарситься. Если не выходит - прикрепите *точный* код, который выполняете, и ошибку.

Comment: temp_dict = json.loads(temp_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not coroutine

Comment: полный код добавил, но ссылку не могу дать, так как платный токен прописан

Comment: Токен не нужно, конечно) Добавьте отладочную печать *print temp_str* (перед командой *json.loads(temp_str)*) и покажите, что именно хранится в *temp_str* непосредственно перед ошибкой. Может, сервер какой-то нехарактерный ответ выдаёт, где этого поля нет вообще - например, пустую строку или ошибку.

Comment: всё, спасибо за помощь, нашел проблему
`temp_str = await resp.text()
        temp_dict = json.loads(temp_str)
        print(temp_dict['results']['p'])`

Answer (score 0):

`requests` модуль содержит сразу обращение к `json`

```
        temp_dict = resp.json()
        print(temp_dict['results']['p'])
```

Думаю, не нужны промежуточные действия через `.text()`